# When is reversing composition order monotonous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f_a(x)=x+\exp(-ax)/a$ be a function, defined on $R_+$ for $a$ positive.
Fix $a$ and $b$ positive, can we show that the sign of $f_a\circ f_b - f_b\circ f_a$ does not change on $R_+$, with $\circ$ stand for the composition?

It seems true empirically, but I have no idea how to prove it.

More generally, is there nice sufficient conditions on $f,g$ such that $f\circ g \geq g\circ f$ ?

Comment: what is $f_b-f_b$?

Comment: it is 0, so its sign does not change.